# Using extents of mask to define rectangular subregions in ITK

Tags: image-processing, itk

I have a large (3D) image `I` and a mask `M` of the same size. I want to use a filter on part of the image described by the mask, but calculating that filter is quite slow.  I would like to take a rectangular sub-region volume out of `I` that contains all the voxels marked in `M`, apply my filter on that sub-region and then insert that processed subregion back into the appropriate place in `M`.  Since this subregion will be much smaller than `I`, it will perform much faster.

I'd be surprised if there wasn't a existing ITK filter to find the subregion extents based on 'M', but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a number of options. The simplest is to use the [LabelStatisticsImageFilter](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1LabelStatisticsImageFilter.html). Then there is the [LabelMap framework](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/group__ITKLabelMap.html) which has the [ShapeLabelObject](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ShapeLabelObject.html) which can be transformed from a regular label image with [LabelImageToShapeLabelMapFilter](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1LabelImageToShapeLabelMapFilter.html) to the run-length encoded label object with attribute.

As you said you have a large image, so memory constrains and streaming may also be of interest to you. I have created an [ITK External Module](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Release_4/Modularization/Add_an_external_module_%28external_module%29) called [itkStreamingSinc](https://github.com/blowekamp/itkStreamingSinc) which contains a filter called [BoundingRegionImageSinc](https://github.com/blowekamp/itkStreamingSinc/blob/master/include/itkBoundingRegionImageSinc.h) to perform streaming and computation of just the bounding image region in an out of core streaming process.